# How to check two matrices for similitude over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lattices, similarity

> **General question.** Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$-matrices over
> $\mathbb{Z}$. How do I algorithmically check whether $A$ and $B$ are similar
> (i.e., conjugate in the ring $\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$)?

I am particularly interested in two special matrices, more on which below.
However, let me first mark some trails (quite possibly leading nowhere):

- If we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by any field, then the problem becomes easy using
  the [Frobenius canonical
  form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form). Unfortunately,
  similarity over fields is not enough: e.g., a square matrix $A$ is similar to
  its transpose $A^{T}$ over any field, but (in general) not over $\mathbb{Z}$.
  See [Is a matrix over a PID similar to its transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732276) for some examples of
  this. This also shows that various standard invariants (invariant factors,
  Jordan forms over $\mathbb{C}$, etc.) are insufficient to guarantee similarity.
- Two matrices $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ are similar if and only
  if the polynomial matrices $tI_{n}-A$ and $tI_{n}-B$ in $\left(
  \mathbb{Z}\left[  t\right]  \right)  ^{n\times n}$ are congruent (i.e.,
  equivalent under left and right multiplication by invertible matrices, not
  necessarily by the same matrix). Indeed, a proof of this fact has been
  sketched in [on similar matrices and polynomial matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66269/) for any commutative ring
  instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, checking similarity over $\mathbb{Z}$ reduces
  to checking congruence over $\mathbb{Z}\left[  t\right]  $. Unfortunately,
  it's not clear if the latter is any easier.
- I wouldn't be surprised if the problem can be reduced from $\mathbb{Z}$ to
  $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for some very high (but not prime) $n$. However, I'm ideally
  interested in a practicable algorithm, which can be used for two $24\times
  24$-matrices for example.

---

How did I get interested in this? The specific problem I started with is
probably less interesting to the wider world, but it provides a useful
benchmark if nothing else. It comes from the study of random-to-top and
top-to-random shuffling on the symmetric group.

Consider a positive integer $n$, and let $S_{n}$ be the symmetric group on the
set $\left\{  1,2,\dotsc,n\right\}  $. We shall define an $n!\times n!$-matrix
$A\in\mathbb{Z}^{n!\times n!}$ whose rows and columns are indexed by
permutations in $S_{n}$. Specifically, for any two permutations $\sigma
,\tau\in S_{n}$, we let the $\left(  \sigma,\tau\right)  $-th entry of this
matrix $A$ be the integer $1$ if the permutation $\tau^{-1}\circ\sigma$ is the
cycle $\left(  1,2,\dotsc,i\right)  $ for some $i\in\left\{  1,2,\dotsc
,n\right\}  $, and be the integer $0$ otherwise. (Note that the cycle $\left(
1\right)  $ is understood to be the identity permutation; thus, all diagonal
entries of $A$ are $1$.) For instance, if $n=3$, then $A$ looks as follows:
\begin{align*}
A=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  ,
\end{align*}
where the elements of $S_{3}$ are ordered in lexicographic order (i.e., using
one-line notation for permutations, we have $\left[  1,2,3\right]  <\left[
1,3,2\right]  <\left[  2,1,3\right]  <\left[  2,3,1\right]  <\left[
3,1,2\right]  <\left[  3,2,1\right]  $). Let $B$ be the transpose $A^{T}$ of
this matrix.

What I'm wondering is whether $A$ and $B$ are similar over $\mathbb{Z}$. This
is easily seen to hold for $n\leq3$. In fact, $A$ is conjugate to $B$ by a
permutation matrix if $n\leq3$. However, a permutation matrix does not suffice
for $n=4$. Could another invertible matrix do the trick? This is the first
case I would like to hear the answer. In this case, explicitly,
\begin{align*}
A &  =\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\\
B &  =A^{T}.
\end{align*}
(This has been generated using [some simple Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUEFqwzAQvBv8h4FcJGICLj0VcsgDAoXcYkJQ5XUrsNe2tG6c33fjGNrqIO1oZ4fZYezxmmcn1vedYjeJk9BzMmzzLM9qanA0qYDYN2wgX4TOSQwziCXeERixvyHBcQ3ft1PHkDyDnkEVZRf4m2IiY3ctNXJ1_qF-HWJfT15Msk9uUO7wyzXl-j_-d2XakMREx59kXgqEbWkttqjKi95_etoowI_uqrNRpZAW-_7uW9LKCW4Emgfyol6lx4fCcXKt1s-pSDJF1h3F6DJ7jEskB_V0XDIw53OBqlrzQdNHyCORE18WkFagY60Tms3B_gBrbGxR&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).)

In more conceptual terms, the matrices $A$ and $B$ describe two Markov chains
on the symmetric group $S_{n}$: the matrix $A$ describes the "top-to-random
shuffle", whereas the matrix $B$ describes the "random-to-top shuffle", or
vice versa, depending on how we identify permutations with card decks.

Algebraically, $A$ and $B$ represent two $\mathbb{Z}$-module endomorphisms of
the group ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[  S_{n}\right]  $: namely, if we set
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}:=\underbrace{\left(  1\right)  }_{\text{a }1\text{-cycle}
}+\underbrace{\left(  1,2\right)  }_{\text{a }2\text{-cycle}}
+\underbrace{\left(  1,2,3\right)  }_{\text{a }3\text{-cycle}}+\cdots
+\underbrace{\left(  1,2,\dotsc,n\right)  }_{\text{an }n\text{-cycle}}
\in\mathbb{Z}\left[  S_{n}\right]  ,
\end{align*}
then $A$ represents right multiplication by $\mathbf{A}$, whereas $B$
represents left multiplication by $\mathbf{A}$. It is well-known (see, e.g.,
Theorem 3 in [Is this sum of cycles invertible in $\mathbb QS_n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308536/) ) that $\prod
_{i\in\left\{  0,1,\dotsc,n-2,n\right\}  }\left(  \mathbf{A}-n\right)  =0$ in
$\mathbb{Z}\left[  S_{n}\right]  $, which shows that both $A$ and $B$ are
diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}$ with diagonal entries $0,1,\dotsc,n-2,n$
(whose multiplicities can also be computed). Section 4 from my Waterloo 2022
talk [The one-sided cycle shuffles in the symmetric group algebra](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/waterloo2022.pdf) gives some more context. If $A$ and $B$ are
similar, then essentially any property of $A$ yields an analogous property of
$B$ and vice versa, which would be very convenient for the study of $A$ and
$B$. Arguably, much is already known about $A$ and $B$, but there are other, less standard, situations in which one similarly wants to jump around between left and right actions.

Comment: There is an algorithm but I am not sure how complicated. For general arithmetic groups it's  harder.  Ill find the reference. It off course Gruewald Segal cover it

Comment: This questions has the references https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77133/conjugacy-in-gln-mathbb-z

Comment: And the overkill reference https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971091?origin=crossref

Comment: For your particular Markov chain maybe the left regular band approach can be used to show you can diagonalize over Z?

Comment: [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.03526) might be of interest

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Alas, $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb Z$ for $n=2$. But thanks for the links, which appaer to solve the most general version of this problem (albeit using more number theory than I am comfortable with)!